# Using super() in constructor

Tags: java

If we, in our program, have just one class, without extending any class. For example

```
public class Point {
    int x, y;
}
```

Compiler creates default constructor and call the super() method acording to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9

```
public class Point {
    int x, y;
    public Point() { 
    super(); 
    }
}
```

Q: As i understand super(); is calling default constructor of super class, but in this case we do not have a super class, so what is super() calling in that case?

Comment: Every class extends Object class.So you have a super class.

Comment: except for Object which extends Chuck Norris

Comment: Ohh God.. people are so busy in answering this basic question that they are not even caring for their TYPOS :P

Comment: @sansix. I renect that sugestion.

Comment: But what is the default constructor of Object class do?

Comment: the default constructor of the Object class creates the object itself

Answer (score 5):

All java classes extend from [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Answer (score 4):

You do have a super class. All classes in Java automatically extend java.lang.Object, regardless of whether you specify it or not.

See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

To take one snippet from that link:

> All classes have at least one constructor. If a class does not
>   explicitly declare any, the Java compiler automatically provides a
>   no-argument constructor, called the default constructor. This default
>   constructor calls the class parent's no-argument constructor, or the
>   Object constructor if the class has no other parent. If the parent has
>   no constructor (Object does have one), the compiler will reject the
>   program.

Comment: Understand. But what is the purpose of constructor of Object class ? Does this question have sense ? :)

Comment: It creates the object (unless you have overridden its constructor by providing one yourself).

Comment: The Java constructor for `Object` doesn't actually do anything interesting, but it serves as the root of the constructor tree; the JVM implementor knows that that constructor is the end of any particular constructor chain. Additionally, plain `Object`s are sometimes used for purposes such as lock objects.

Comment: What you saying is that we can override constructor of Object?

Comment: @user16401: Not just can, but should. It allows you to define how you want objects of that class to be created. For example, if you have a class called EmailAccounts, in your constructor you might want to set a username and email for every user - you'd need to create your own constructor for this.

Answer (score 1):

The default contructor is `Object`, which all Java objects inherit from

Comment: Ok, it is clear now. But what is the default constructor of Object class do? Sorry maby is stupid question ..

Comment: It is handle by the JVM, I think it mainly do the memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

In java, every class has a super class. If none is explicitly given, then it's `Object`

Answer (score 0):

All Java Classes extends from Object, so if you are not extending any class, by super you are calling constructor of Object class.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is the super type of all in java. `Super()` it will call `Object` class.

Comment: @sureshatta: Told me I wasn't changing enough characters. You need to edit one more instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Each class in Java implicitly extends Object Class. So you can always call super() from the constructor of any class.

Again in Object class there is no explicit constructor. Compiler creates a default one and **the default constructor of the Object class creates the object itself**.